# Spring Data: MongoTemplate dependency on Service or on custom Repository

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I've currently took the approach by injecting `MongoTemplate` field into my repository class:

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MPIPatientRepository implements IMPIPatientRepository {

    private final MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

}
```

After having reading and examining some docs and code over there, it's not clear to me if best approach by using `MongoTemplate` place is into a `Repository` class, or inside a `Service` class.

I mean, I've seen a lot of code over there, that `MongoTemplate` as a `Service` layer dependency.

Something like that:

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CustomerService {

    private final MontoTemplate mongoTemplate;
}
```

Could some one give me some lights over that doubt?